# If I exclude Tor nodes using option ExcludeNodes, will it exclude also some Tor nodes select by options EntryNodes and ExitNodes?

Tags: configuration, relays

I have these options in my torrc file:

```
ExitNodes {at},{be},{bg},{ch},{cz},{cy},{de},{hk},{is},{jp},{lu},{nl},{no},{pa},{ro},{sc},{sk},{si},{ua},{vg}
EntryNodes {at},{be},{bg},{ch},{cz},{cy},{de},{hk},{is},{jp},{lu},{nl},{no},{pa},{ro},{sc},{sk},{si},{ua},{vg}
StrictNodes 1
```

And also an option to exclude nodes with low bandwidth (I wrote a [...] because the list is very long):

```
ExcludeNodes "$000a10d43011ea4928a35f610405f92b4433b4dc,$0011bd2485ad45d984ec4159c88fc066e5e3300e,$00152dfab972a3f8b08648e14a7b098cc29483e9,$00240ecb2b535aa4c1e1874d744dfa6af2e5e941,$00283b5564e3072dcddab31d6ef622dd49bf524f,$0036fa36ab435fd5d0f640626636867ebfb72c68,[...]"
```

Let's suppose that some relays specified by ExcludeNodes is of a country selected by options ExitNodes and EntryNodes.

/\ In this case, will option ExcludeNodes exclude these exit nodes even if they are matched by options ExitNodes and EntryNodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> **EntryNodes** node,node,...
>
> [...]
>
> The **ExcludeNodes** option overrides this option: any node listed in both **EntryNodes** and **ExcludeNodes** is treated as excluded.
>
> [...]

> **ExitNodes** node,node,...
>
> [...]
>
> The **ExcludeNodes** option overrides this option: any node listed in both **ExitNodes** and **ExcludeNodes** is treated as excluded.
>
> [...]

Also note that using `StrictNodes 1` and a long list of `ExcludeNodes` will prevent you from accessing some onion services.

Comment: Yes, I know that can prevent user from reaching .onion sites, I just want to exclude nodes with low bandwidth to take more advantage when watching videos on some sites.